# How do I read a text file in Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

Can someone provide a simplest-case example of reading a text file?

Comment: Do you mean in Objective-C ? Anyway, first hit with Google: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/strings/Articles/readingFiles.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C you can do something like

```
NSString* s = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"yourfile.txt" 
                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want plain C (and not objective-C), then:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFSIZE 100

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    FILE *fp = fopen("filename.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "File not found\n");
        return 1;
    }
    while(fgets(buf, BUFSIZE, stdin) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", buf);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```